# JSX and TSX coexist in Next js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, tsconfig, tsx

I created my project in JSX base. I created a TSX file and Next js create tsconfig.json automatically but an error occurs:

> ```
> ./app/layout.jsx:2:0
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@components/navegador/Nav'
>   1 | import './globals.scss';
> > 2 | import Nav from '@components/navegador/Nav';
>   3 | import Foot from '@components/footer/Foot';
>   4 | 
>   5 | export const metadata = {
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
> ```

Those components are in JSX.

I tried to delete tsconfig.json and the error doesn´t occur but obviously my tsx file show errors.

tsconfig.json:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: please add your tsconfig file with your question.

Comment: ok, I will add right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating paths configuration of your tsconfig.json should resolve the module resolution issue when using absolute paths with the '@components' alias.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...rest of your config settings
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```